# Bokeh notification Paragraph widget -- can't insert newline

Tags: python, bokeh, paragraph

In bokeh/python, I'm trying to have a Paragraph widget act like an output console. So I periodically update its text. However I can't seem to insert newline characters into that box. This means the console is almost unreadable. Here is a minimal example:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Paragraph, Button
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure

notifications = Paragraph(text='initial text')#, name=name, width=width, height=height)
button = Button(label="Click me to add text")
def callback():
    notifications.text += 'more text' + '\n'
button.on_click(callback)

# Set up layout and add to document
box = widgetbox(notifications, button)
curdoc().add_root(row(box))
```

The '\n' in the line

```
notifications.text += 'more text' + '\n'
```

does nothing, whether it's there or not. I've also tried

```
notifications.text += 'more text' + '<br />'
```

in case html is interpreted here, and it doesn't work. What else can I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the Div widget, which supports HTML, see

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.markups.html#bokeh.models.widgets.markups.Div

Your example then becomes:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div, Button
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure

notifications = Div(text='initial text')#, name=name, width=width, height=height)
button = Button(label="Click me to add text")
def callback():
    notifications.text += 'more text' + '</br>'
button.on_click(callback)

# Set up layout and add to document
box = widgetbox(notifications, button)
curdoc().add_root(row(box))
```